# How can I retrieve data in Firebase and display with listview?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-storage

I'm new in writing code and I started in Flutter & Dart
also done to get data from firebase Cloud-Store and I want to display as like as list view for customer products

## `here is my firebase`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iws4W.png)

Answer (score 0):

in order to receive data from Firebase cloud store you need to use StreamBuilder widget. It will listen to changes and update itself automatically each time data in your database change
here is an example of using StreamBuilder and displaying data within a list view:

```
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

final firestore = fb.firestore();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: firestore.collection('my_collection').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            // Get the data from the snapshot
            var data = snapshot.data.documents[index];

            // Use the data to build your list view
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(data['title']),
              subtitle: Text(data['description']),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```